# How to submit a form and delete a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models in a rails project: `Link` and `Campaign`.
In the show.html.erb for `Link` I have a form to create a new `Campaign`
It looks like this

```
 <%= form_for :campaign, url: campaigns_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: current_user.email %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :product, value: @link.product %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :title, value: @link.title %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :website, value: current_user.website %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :productlink, value: @link.url %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :description, value: @link.description %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :date, value: Date.today.to_s %>
   <br>
   <br>
   <%= f.submit :"Let's Go Make Some Money", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

This works. My problem is deleting the post for `Link` while creating the new post based on it for `Campaign`. Basically, I want to submit a form and delete something else.

Comment: Send link id in hidden field and get in campaign controller (create action) ... delete that

Comment: @Mukesh how would I go about doing that? I've been looking it up for a while, and I still can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the id of the link you want to destroy in the form_for:

```
  <%= form_for @campaign, :url => { :controller => :campaign, :action=>:create, :link_id => @link.id } do |f| %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: current_user.email %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :product, value: @link.product %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :title, value: @link.title %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :website, value: current_user.website %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :productlink, value: @link.url %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :description, value: @link.description %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :date, value: Date.today.to_s %>
   <br>
   <br>
   <%= f.submit :"Let's Go Make Some Money", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

In your links_controller.rb:

```
 def show
      @campaign = Campaign.new
    end
```

And in your campaigns_controller.rb:
    def show
      @
    end

```
def create
  @link = Link.find(params[:link_id])
  @link.destroy
  ...
  # create campaign
end
```

Comment: When I do that I get a syntax error... syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...r.append= form_for (:campaign, link_id: @link.id), url: cam... ... ^ and also yntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ... (:campaign, link_id: @link.id), url: campaigns_path do |f| ... ... ^ Do you know the problem?

Comment: @SamHenrichs I've edited the first line of the view, try with it

Comment: I think there is a small error. I'm getting a route error, telling me `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"campaign", :id=>"12"}` Any fix? I think there needs to be a divide between id for the campaign and the link. Thanks for the help, Sam